# Add class properties to a provided Bundle : how to?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.3

Our team is having a bit of a headache while modifying our core model.

Our problem :

We have a bundle, let's name it COREBundle. We load it via composer on every app to get the very basic required to boot our system.

The COREBundle provides a Customer Entity. 
Each app has some special customer properties that we want to add : how to proceed ?
Of course the complexity here is to make everything work with the COREBundle provided.

We are exploring the idea of having some MappedSuperClasses but it means we will need to modify all our entities in ALL our apps, which will be extremely time-consuming.

Help? Thank you!

Comment: MappedSuperClasses seems to be the solution. It seems legit to update your entities from every apps if you update the core bundle.

Comment: Do all your apps share a single database ? if not and if all your app use, let's say doctrine, you can make your coreBundle provide a Trait with basic customer properties and, on the app side, have a entity using your trait (and maybe implementing an interface) and defining only the Entity/Table annotation and adding extra properties ... this way you dn't need mappedsuperclass ...